# Functions or methods that throw errors in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, error-handling, swift2

When you find a 3rd party function or method in Swift that throws an error, is there any way to know what errors it might throw?

That info isn't available in the function or method signature. It only says it throws something...

Comment: If the API / documentation doesn't tell you, then you can't know.

Comment: definitely sounds like a bug, not a feature. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is propagated in standard way. try to simulate the error by passing wrong data to the function or disable some hardware (like network adapter ...) and try to dump it

```
import Foundation

func foo() throws ->Void {
    // anonymous Error
    struct Error: ErrorType {
        var msg = "error msg"
    }
    throw Error()
}

func boo() throws ->Void {
    // anonymous NSError
    let e = NSError(domain: "domain", code: 100, userInfo: nil)
    throw e
}


do {
    try foo()
} catch let e {
    print("foo throws:", e.dynamicType)
    dump(e)

}
do {
    try boo()
} catch let e {
    print("boo throws:", e.dynamicType)
    dump(e)
}
/* prints

foo throws: (Error #1)
▿ (foo () throws -> ()).(Error #1)
- msg: error msg
boo throws: NSError
▿ Error Domain=domain Code=100 "(null)" #0
- NSObject: Error Domain=domain Code=100 "(null)"

*/
```